# django url parameter has space,How to solve it?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm a newbie for program and study django now. I have one question.

example:
my product title: classic photo frame
my url: url(r'^(.+)/$', products, name='products'),
I open through url with www.xxx.com/classic photo frame/ 
it works,but the this url has space, I know it's not correct.
I add - to parameter,such as classic-photo-frame. It works too.
But this way, - will show in front-end page.

How can I resolve?
url shows **/classic-photo-frame** but the front-end page is **classic photo frame**

Thank you.

Comment: What do u mean by "will show in front-end page"?

Comment: I mean show in template html page.

Comment: Are you not sending it in context?

Answer (score 0):

the best way use SlugField .
For more information check this link. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

and you can add this line `prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',), }` to your custom django admin class  for auto generate slug in admin.
after this you can use slug in your urls